# getData() of Users created from Admin backend

Tags: backend, admin-user

I have created users from backend admin i.e. System->Permissions->Users .
Now I want to obtain details of every users that are created. Can anyone please answer me how to obtain created user details?

Comment: What do you mean by "details"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-
 To get all user

```
$adminUserModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userCollection = $adminUserModel->getCollection()->load(); 
print_r($userCollection->getData());
```

To get all the Roles

```
   $roles = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getCollection();
   foreach($roles as $role):
      echo '<br/>Role : '.$role->getId()." | ".$role->getRoleName();
   endforeach;
```

To get the Role users

```
  $roles_users = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/roles_user_collection');
  foreach($roles_users as $roleuser):
   $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($roleuser->getUserId());
   echo '<br/>User : '.$user->getUsername()." | ".$user->getFirstname();
  endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush.
Can you please help me how to get Users details with specific role?

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Dear i want details of users created that have specific role. For example, All user details that have role id = '3' .

Comment: You have join user and role table